# Electron app.on('ready'... never being called and electron window never showing. Seemingly tied to specific Git repository

Tags: node.js, windows, git, electron

## Summary

I'm new to Electron development, and helping to lead a small project at work creating an electron application. After working inside the Git repository for a day or so, the electron window suddenly stopped appearing. I've determined that the function callback I give in `app.on('ready' callback)` is never being called.

My workstation setup:
NodeJS version: 12.9.0 (Also tested with 10.16.3)
Yarn Version: 1.17.3
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise

Originally, I was loosely following [Ryan Brockhoff's Medium post](https://medium.com/@brockhoff/using-electron-with-react-the-basics-e93f9761f86f) about using Electron with React when electron started malfunctioning, but I've since cut a brand new Git branch and set up only an extremely minimal Electron project, and the same problem appears.

Electron does not malfunction the same way system-wide. I'm able to run the [electron-api-demos](https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos) perfectly. In addition, an older test directory where I was experimenting with electron still functions.

When I attempt to run the broken electron repository, Task Manager does show three electron processes as children under the command line process. When I run a well-functioning electron process, the electron process is shown as a parent process

I confirmed the 'ready' callback function is never being called through placing `console.log` statements inside the function, as well as a print statement when the callback is being assigned. the callback assignment print statement is being reached, and I can see the output on the console, but the print statement inside the callback function is never being reached, and that output is never being printed to the console.

## Troubleshooting

I've done many troubleshooting steps at this point:

Troubleshooting: I deleted and re-cloned the Git repository elsewhere on my computer
Result: problem persists

Troubleshooting: Let the program run for a while, maybe it needs to set something up before it's ready
Result: After 10+ minutes, no change

Troubleshooting: I downloaded the electron-api-demos repository to see if electron worked in that project
Result: electron-api-demos works perfectly as expected

Troubleshooting: I downgraded my electron version from "^6.0.3" to "^6.0.1", which works on a different project on my computer
Result: problem persists

Troubleshooting: I created a new empty Git branch, with no code and attempted to create a new minimal electron project in the same git repository I had been seeing the problem in
Result: problem re-emerges

Troubleshooting: Completely re-installed Node JS, changing versions from 12.x latest to 10.x LTS
Result: no change

Troubleshooting: cloned and attempted to run the project inside an Ubuntu Virtual Machine
Result: Success, project works as expected

Troubleshooting: Asked Co-worker to install project on their Windows 10 machine
Result: Success, co-worker could not re-produce my issue

## Code

I set up an extremely minimal project to re-produce this issue. The following is my current project:

package.json

```
{
  ...
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "electron-start": "electron ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^6.0.3"
  },
  ...
}
```

main.js

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')      

function createWindow () {
  console.log("inside the on ready callback"); //for troubleshooting
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})  
  win.loadFile('index.html')   
}      

console.log("outside the function"); //for troubleshooting
app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run `yarn electron-start`, the following prints out to my console:

```
yarn run v1.17.3
$ electron .

 outside the function
```

The print statement for inside the on ready callback is never reached. No errors are being emitted.

## Conclusion

At this point, my suspicion is that there is something on my computer that is messed up. The Git repository that this code runs inside seems to be causing problems as well. I've done a lot of googling and I can't find anyone else facing this problem. The only thing I can think from here is to try scrapping our entire git repository and creating a new one (which may or may not be possible), and taking my computer into tech support for a possible replacement. Any clues on how to move forward would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hello, I'm not that experienced with yarn, but could you try starting your app with npm instead? E.g. `npm run electron-start`. If that doesn't help I'd suggest creating an issue in the [Electron github repo](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/new/choose). Btw you've done a really good job troubleshooting the problem on your own +1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Alright, so I eventually did find a solution to this. This error was caused by attempting to install extra devtools using [electron-devtools-installer](https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/electron-devtools-installer). I found that the error was caused by data being left over in the %AppData%/electron directory, and the %AppData%/[projectname] directory. Deleting these two directories solves this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been trying to find a solution for this for a few days now, your comment finally got me on the right track. For anyone else finding this, an issue has been filed: https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/electron-devtools-installer/issues/110 . The problem relates to windows 10's dark mode and is a bug within electron currently

Comment: I'll add to this... you only need to delete the `DevTools Extensions` file in `%APPDATA%/[projectname]`

Answer (score 3):

Workaround: Call `app.removeAllListeners('ready')` before `app.on('ready', createWindow)`

Comment: Any reason why this works or thoughts on what other problems this might cause?

Comment: For one, it seems to affect extension loading - I'm getting "TypeError: BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/electron-devtools-installer/dist/index.js:80:30)" if I use this.